# Facebook Selenium How can I get the number of likes

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, error-handling

I am trying to get the numbers of people who liked the post with the below code. I tried both methods both are not working. It does return error code.

Could someone assist, appreciate that.

**Source Code :** https://m.facebook.com/ufi/reaction/profile/browser/?ft_ent_identifier=3647203655325514

[image]

```
def get_likes(self):
    return self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@data-store="{"reactionType":1}"]/span/span').get_attribute("innerHTML")

def get_likes(self):
return self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@data-store="{\"reactionType\":1}"]/span/span').get_attribute("innerHTML")
```

**SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//span[@data-store="{"reactionType":1}"]/span/span' is not a valid XPath expression.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also tried to escape in different ways, but same result - Seems that xpath has a problem with the `"` from the html and means that they were closed, so

`driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@id="u_0_r"]').get_attribute('data-store')`

only detects the opening `{`

Id of parent `div` is generated automatically and position of icons in it is ordered by count of clicks.

**You could use the `class` of the `i` tag until there is a better solution, that really would interest me:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Program Files\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe')

html_content = '''
<div class="scrollAreaColumn">
        <span name="one" data-store="{"reactionType":1}">
         <span>133</span>
        </span>
        <span name="two" data-store="{"reactionType":1}">
         <i class="_2ep2 img sp_FnpQQMXWL5W sx_4760b1"></i>
         <span>128</span>
        </span>
        <span name="three" data-store="{"reactionType":1}">
         <i class="_2ep2 img sp_FnpQQMXWL5W sx_4760b1 xyz"></i>
         <span>128</span>
        </span>
</div>       
'''
driver.get("data:text/html;charset=utf-8,{html_content}".format(html_content=html_content))
count = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//i[@class="_2ep2 img sp_FnpQQMXWL5W sx_4760b1"]/following-sibling::span').text
print(count)

driver.close()
```

Comment: Bingo, You are genius!!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this xpath:

```
'//span[@data-store=\"{\'reactionType\':1}\"]//span[@data-sigil="reaction_profile_tab_count"]'
```

Comment: Appreciate that, but same error message. Is it something wrong in the data-store not the main xpath element?

Comment: I edited the xpath, I did not notice it earlier, It was complaining about nested quotes.

Comment: try now and see if give back the result.

Comment: the error message change to NoSuchElement as the element come with "{\"reactionType\":1}". Is challenging...